# "of utmost importance" vs "of the utmost importance"

Tags: word-choice, definite-articles, superlative-degree

Which one is the correct form between "of utmost" and "of the utmost"?

> 1. Your attendance at the meeting is **of the utmost importance**.
> 2. Your attendance at the meeting is **of utmost importance**.

I've found an old forum discussion [here](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic56221.html), but they don't really conclude anything. The second answer to the question is

> They mean the same thing. Use with the article seems far more
>   prevalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of them are correct. It depends on whether we should use the definite article *the* before *utmost* or not.

If you don't use *utmost*, it should be *of importance* as importance is a mass (abstract) noun which doesn't require an article.

However, if you use *utmost*, you could use the *the* because utmost is in the superlative form meaning *greatest* or *most extreme*.

According to Oxford Online Dictionary, there is an example of "[a matter of **the** utmost importance](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/utmost)" and according to Merriam-Webster, there is "[a matter of utmost concern](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utmost)".

They show both of them are correct.

As FumbleFingers has shown in the comment, the linked [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+the+utmost+importance%2Cof+utmost+importance&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20the%20utmost%20importance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20utmost%20importance%3B%2Cc0) shows there is no big difference in their usage in American English. However, British English seems to favor *of the utmost importance* according to this [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+the+utmost+importance%2Cof+utmost+importance&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20the%20utmost%20importance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20utmost%20importance%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

The second answer in that discussion is the right answer; both forms are correct although use of "the utmost" is the most prevalent.

Comment: Yes, but *American* usage in particular is shifting more [towards *not* including the article](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+the+utmost+importance%2Cof+utmost+importance&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20the%20utmost%20importance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20utmost%20importance%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: That's very interesting @FumbleFingers, apparently the same is true for [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+the+utmost+importance%2Cof+utmost+importance&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20the%20utmost%20importance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20utmost%20importance%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Gabriel: To a *much* lesser degree. The AmE chart shows the article-less form to now be almost exactly as common as the "original", but in BrE it's still not even *half* as common. And half of what they *do* include in the BrE corpus are probably misclassified texts - that's about par for the course in Google Books.

Comment: After the year 2000 both AmE and BE show an upraise in the usage of [the article form](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+the+utmost+importance%2Cof+utmost+importance&year_start=1900&year_end=2016&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20the%20utmost%20importance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20utmost%20importance%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Off-topic: I think this is an interesting discussion in its own right, and I see the same in the Dutch language: a population stops using a certain phrase in a certain way, and dictionaries and grammar rules follow. Languages evolve for sure, but I'm not convinced that the world is better served by allowing just any change just because there's a large population behind it